# Cannot issue a "ping -6" google.com

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ping, ipv6

I am trying to connect via RDP from my PC to a server. They are in different networks (WAN) and the server is only visible via ipv6.

I cannot connect to this server from the network where my PC is located. I tried to use the same PC but a different network (from my smartphone) and it works fine.

So I assume something in my LAN is blocking RDP to ipv6.

So I tried to test and issue a ping -6 google.com for testing and it fails. "Ping request could not find host google.com". Ping with -4 works.

What should be the reason for this failure. How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: ping google.com works by the way. IPv6 is also activated in my network adapter. I can RDP other external PCs using IPv4.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Windows' `ping` (which I'm guessing this is), but could it be that `-6` forces the name resolution itself to go via IPv6? Do you have an IPv6 DNS available and detected by Windows?

Comment: I am not sure the DNS I am using supports IPv6, but I tried with google DNS servers on the network adapter properties, under ipv6 protocol,but it had no effect. Besides, I cannot connect (RDP) a remote computer giving its public ipv6 number, so I believe DNS would not play a role here.

Comment: In that case, did you try pinging the computer's IPv6 address? Also, _cannot connect_ is quite vague - what error is reported?

Comment: I think I have managed to isolate the problem I little bit more. I have two PCs connected to the same network. Both running Windows 10. One of them respond to thte ping command nicely, the other provides the error: Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again. I have checked both network adapter have the same services enabled. What else could I check?

Comment: Try comparing the lists under Adapter status -> Details.

Comment: Make sure your DNS server also responds with AAAA records, some don't.